# A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "Admin\UserBundle\Entity\Extension" passed to the choice field

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I installed easyAdmin Bundle(symfony2) then :

1. I combined it with fosUserBundle.
2. I add an entity "extension".
3. So i created a user but when i tried to edit the account in the
   dashboard i get this error :

   > ### A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type  "Admin\UserBundle\Entity\Extension" passed to the choice field

So can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the following question, but what about adding a `__toString()` method?

In your Extension:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->fieldYouWantToDisplayAsChoice;
}
```

For example, if your Extension has a property `username`, you can use `return 
$this->username`, and the choice field will be populated with the `username` property of each user.

See [magic __toString](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).